# MS-SQL - Extracting numerical portion of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an MS-SQL table, with a column titled 'ImportCount'.
Data in this column follows the below format:

```
ImportCount
[Schedules] 1376 schedule items imported from location H:\FOLDERA\AA\XX...
[Schedules] 10201 schedule items imported from location H:\FOLDERZZ\PERS\YY...
[Schedules] 999 schedule items imported from location R:\PERS\FOLDERA\AA\XX...
[Schedules] 21 schedule items imported from location H:\FOLDERA\MM\2014ZZ...
```

What I would like to do is extract that numerical portion of the data (which varies in length), but am struggling to get the right result.  Would appreciate any help on this!
Thanks.

Comment: Which is your database? sql server, MySql, oracle etc.

Comment: it seems u hv some predifined text coming before and after the number count..so take a substring accordingly and it should work...Seems pretty straight fwd to me...try like this  SELECT SUBSTRING( ImportCount, 12, CHARINDEX('schedule',ImportCount-1 ));

Comment: TechDo, aplogies, its MS-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select SUBSTRING(ImportCount,13,patindex('% schedule items%',ImportCount)-13) from table name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select left(ImportCount, patindex('%[^0-9]%', ImportCount+'.') - 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..You can declare it as a SQL function also.

```
DECLARE @intText INT
DECLARE @textAplhaNumeric varchar(100)

set @textAplhaNumeric = '1376 schedule items imported from location'
SET @intText = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @textAplhaNumeric)

BEGIN
WHILE @intText > 0
BEGIN
SET @textAplhaNumeric = STUFF(@textAplhaNumeric, @intText, 1, '' )
SET @intText = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @textAplhaNumeric)
END
END

Select @textAplhaNumeric //output is 1376
```

It will work in case of NULL or empty values.

Comment: This does not work in the case where he there is a numeric value in the location part.. if will concatenate all the numerical values.. In the case of '[Schedules] 21 schedule items imported from location H:\FOLDERA\MM\2014ZZ...', it will return '212014'

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT LEFT(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Val+'a')-1) from(
    SELECT
       STUFF(ImportCount, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ImportCount)-1, '') Val
    FROM YourTable
)x
```